# Psycopg2 is not only accepts None (Nonetype) as a cell entry that can be Null when using %s but not with f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am inserting data into a Postgres DB using Psycopg2 using:

```
params = "ts, price, volume"
entry = (1234567, None, 3)
cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO stock_data ({params}) VALUES {entry};")
```

I have used this pattern of f-string with params and a tuple entry countless times with no issue.

For additional information, the `price` column does not have any constraints and is a `numeric(5)`.

For this particular instance, it is giving me the error:

`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist`

Everything I tried resulted in this error. What did end up working was not using an f-string. The following entry worked:

`cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO stock_data ({params}) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);", entry)`

My understanding is that these are identical. Why would the latter work, but including the entry directly into the `INSERT` statement not work?

Comment: hmmm.  Sql Injection, anyone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Format` just inserts the value into a string:

```
>>> x = None
>>> f"What should I expect here? {x}"
'What should I expect here? None'
```

You pass the already formatted string to `cur.execute()`. When you pass a query text with placeholders and arguments, the function *knows* how to convert them.

```
>>> cur.mogrify(f"INSERT INTO stock_data ({params}) VALUES {entry};")
b'INSERT INTO stock_data (ts, price, volume) VALUES (1234567, None, 3);'

>>> cur.mogrify(f"INSERT INTO stock_data ({params}) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);", entry)
b'INSERT INTO stock_data (ts, price, volume) VALUES (1234567, NULL, 3);'
```

It would be best if you always used placeholders and arguments in cursor.execute(), also for your own safety. Read [Passing parameters to SQL queries](http://psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), where you can find this

> Warning
>
> Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the warning!